# Trying to do a three table join displaying all columns

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to do a three table join to display all columns. Only two of the tables have a key in common. Below is the code for the tables I already have:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacultyID int,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
EMail varchar(60),
BirthDate DATE,
Numbr_Courses int,
PRIMARY KEY (FacultyID)
);

CREATE TABLE Courses(
CourseID int,
CourseDisc varchar(4),
CourseNum varchar(4),
NumbrCred varchar(1),
FirstYrOffered int,
CourseTitle varchar(75),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseID)
);

CREATE TABLE Faculty_Courses(
InstanceID int,
FacultyID int,
CourseDisc varchar(4),
CourseNum varchar(4),
CourseTitle varchar(75),
PRIMARY KEY (InstanceID),
FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID)
);
```

The two tables that have the same key is Faculty and Faculty_Course. I have attempted one peice of code that only gave me back an error. I guess I am having real trouble understanding how to do proper code for joining tables. My attempted code is below:

```
SELECT Faculty.*, Faculty_Courses.*
    FROM  Faculty INNER JOIN Courses
        ON Faculty.FacultyID=Faculty_Courses.FacultyID
```

This gave me back the following error:

**ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'Faculty'**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm - you only have two tables in that join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your `Faculty_Courses` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty_Courses(
  InstanceID int,
  FacultyID int,
  CourseID int,
  PRIMARY KEY (InstanceID),
  FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES Courses(CourseID)
);
```

And then join all three tables together:

```
SELECT F.*, FC.*, C.*
FROM  Faculty F
INNER JOIN Faculty_Courses FC ON F.FacultyID = FC.FacultyID
INNER JOIN Courses C ON C.CourseID = FC.CourseID
```

You probably only really want some of the columns from `F` (Faculty) and `C` (Courses) and can mostly ignore the `FC` columns as they are just used for mapping between `F` and `C`

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised your `factory_courses` table doesn't have a reference to `courses`.

Either way, with your current query, you are selecting from `faculty` and `courses` but aliasing `faculty_courses` -- you cannot do that.  This is what your current query should look like:

```
select *
from faculty f 
   join faculty_courses fc on f.facultyid = fc.facultyid
```

---

To `join` the 3rd table, if you had a `courseid` in your `faculty_courses` table, perhaps something like this:

```
select *
from faculty f 
   join faculty_courses fc on f.facultyid = fc.facultyid
   join courses c on fc.courseid = c.courseid
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a join on two tables without actually linking two columns from those tables; joining `Faculty` and `Courses` using columns from `Faculty` and `Faculty_Courses`.
Since no column exists with unique values linking `Courses` with any other table, you cannot perform a join with `Courses`.
So you should join `Faculty` and `Faculty_courses`:

```
SELECT Faculty.*, Faculty_Courses.*
    FROM  Faculty INNER JOIN Faculty_Courses
        ON Faculty.FacultyID=Faculty_Courses.FacultyID
```